# Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>" в "string"

Tags: c#

помогите пожалуйста закончить эксперимент: имеется код поиска похожей строки и проблема рисуется при попытке читать строки из файла

```
это 
   string[] array = { "123", "456", "789", "666", "765" };
        string item = "666";
        var res = array.Select((str, ind) => new { str, ind }).Where(a => a.str.Equals(item)).FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(res == null ? "Элемент не найден" : res.ind.ToString());

 я перестроил в это где и получил ошибку пытаясь строку считать из файла 
string[] array = { "123", "456", "789", "666", "765" };
        string item = System.IO.File.ReadLines("2.txt") ;
        var res = array.Select((str, ind) => new { str, ind }).Where(a => a.str.Equals(item)).FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine(res == null ? "Элемент не найден" : res.ind.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();


 как это исправить?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.ReadLines` возвращает `IEnumerable<string>`:

```
IEnumerable<string> items = System.IO.File.ReadLines("2.txt");
```

Соответственно

```
var res = array.Select((str, ind) => new { str, ind }).
  Where(a => items.Contains(a.str)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: не проканало  выдает - Не удается неявно преобразовать тип "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>" в "string[]". Существует явное преобразование (возможно, пропущено приведение типов).

Comment: @asex Уже исправлено.

Comment: проконало. спасибо огромное я два дня перевел а решение за вами.

Comment: а подскажите пожалуйста как перестроить код что бы сохранить результат в текстовый файл. пройдет ли такой номер?

Comment: `System.IO.File.AppendAllText((res == null)? "" : res.str);`

Comment: что-то не то если код до вывода в консоль идет ругань - невозможно испольсовать лок переменку res перед её использованием а если после ругань на AppendAllText. к тому же как быть с самим текстовым файлом -"1.txt"?;

Comment: `System.IO.File.AppendAllText("1.txt", (res == null)? "" : res.str);`

Comment: собирается без ошибок но файл пуст.........?